# Android can't detect screen rotation

Tags: android, android-screen

I have a problem with detecting the screen rotation. I have even tried adding the `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"`.

Any help is welcome.

This is my code for the check:

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
     Log.v("o", "oo");
  } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
     Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Caution: Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the "screen size"
> also changes when the device switches between portrait and landscape
> orientation. Thus, if you want to prevent runtime restarts due to
> orientation change when developing for API level 13 or higher (as
> declared by the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion attributes), you
> must include the "screenSize" value in addition to the "orientation"
> value. That is, you must decalare
> android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"

From https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html